# Magento2 : Event on place order after

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, magento-2.1.7

I want to add some logic after place order using `order_id`. For this I tried `sales_order_place_after` event, but in this event I'm not getting `order_id`. And `order_id` is coming into event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` but this event only triggering on frontend.

I want to add some logic for both orders (frontend and backend).

Which event should I use so that I can add some logic stuff for backend orders as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need event

```
sales_order_save_commit_after
```

get Data in observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();


    }
```